# Initialise non-const pointer with this in const member function

Tags: c++, pointers

If have a class `Link` for a linked list implementation:

```cpp
class Link {
public:
    string value;
    // constructor etc.
    Link* insert(Link* n);
    // other member functions
    Link* advance(int n) const;
private:
    // ...    
}
```

In the const member function `Link* advance(int n) const`, I want to advance by `n` elements in the list and get a pointer to that element. To that end, I want to initialise a pointer with the `this` pointer:

```cpp
Link* Link::advance(int n) const {
    if (this==0) return 0;
    Link* p = this;
    // do stuff with p
    return p;
}
```

This doesn't work, because `Link* p = this;` is trying to initialise a `Link*` with a `const Link*`. If I change it to `const Link* p = this;` however, my `return p;` returns the wrong type.

I think the function should be `const` as it doesn't change anything, but I also want it to return a non-const pointer, because I want to use it to modify elements in my list. Is there a better way than something ugly such as

```cpp
Link* Link::advance(int n) const {
    if (this==0) return 0;
    const Link* p = this;
    // do stuff with p
    return const_cast<Link*>(p);
}
```

to achieve this?

Comment: Using `Link *p = const_cast<Link*>(p);`  works?.

Comment: Why would the return type not be const? From what I understand, you want to be able to peek at the n-th element of `Link` even for const lists. Why not returning a pointer to const then?

Comment: `if (this==0) return 0;` is useless: if this is 0 you'll have a SIGSEV

Comment: @MassimoCosta: Not at all guaranteed. Only if the function is virtual (and the compiler doesn't optimise away the vtable access) does it involve using `this` before calling the member function.

Comment: @MassimoCosta: Where would you add `Link *p = const_cast<Link*>(p);`?

Comment: @JBL: Sorry, I think my question wasn't quite clear, I've added the class declaration to the question. I want to be able to modify the `Link` to which the return value of `advance` points.

Comment: @Benjamin: at the second line of the advance method; use this syntax to assign `this` to `p`

Comment: @Massimo: I guess you mean `Link *p = const_cast<Link*>(this);` (and not `<Link*>(p)`), and yes, that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to MODIFY elements in your linked list, the function should NOT be `const` in the first place, since a `const` function is based on the fact that you are not modifying the data in the object you pass in (and if that's a linked list, it also applies to any subsequent members of the list). You should also not leak objects that allow your class to be modified, such as returning a pointer or reference to elements within the object.

If you actually want to modify the contents of the list in this function, then make the function non-const. If you want to have a function that is `const` for practical reasons (passing a `const` value in), then have a second variant that is `const` and doesn't modify the content (and returns a `const Link*`).

Comment: I don't want this function to modify anything (hence `const`), but I want to use the pointer it returns to modify another `Link`. `Link` might be a bad name as it is really just one element of the list, not the list itself.

Comment: But if you are modifying the elements IN the list, then your function is technically not `const`, because your returned value is used to modify the content of the `Link`, which is what I said in "You should also not leak objects that allow your class to be modified" - make the function not `const` and live with the fact that it is never going to be a true `const` function. There are other solutions, using `const_cast` and so on, but that's wrong in this particular case, because what you are trying to do is not a `const` operation.

Comment: I have added the class declaration to my question, showing how `Link` is not the actual list. I see how for example with `advance(0)` the function could be used to modify the very `Link` it was called from, and you say a const function should not allow to do that, right?

Comment: It doesn't matter. You don't return pointers to objects that can be modified from a `const` function. Make it non-`const` and live with that. If you want a `const Link* advance(int n) const` variant for those cases when you want a `const Link*` returned, that's your choice. But if `Link*` is not `const`, then don't make the function `const`, because it breaks the constness at least for `n=0`.